# React onChange event in checkbox is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning react js, and I am trying to do some test assignment, but I can not fix the issue with onchange function. It is not working properly and browser shows no error.
I've tried

```
  handleInputChange(evt) {
    dispatch(changeSortKey(evt.target.checked))
  }
```

and

```
  handleInputChange(evt) {
    dispatch(changeSortKey(evt.target.value))
  }
```

but it didn't help.
Here's a code:

```
<Input placeholder="Sort by price"
       defaultChecked={this.props.sortListKey}
       onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}/>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {   .....
  const sortKey = state.sortKey;

  return {    .....
    sortListKey: sortKey    
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({    .....
  handleInputChange(evt) {
    dispatch(changeSortKey(evt.target.checked))
  }
});
```

The action creator:,

```
export function changeSortKey(sortKey) {
  return { type: SORT_BY_PRICE, payload: sortKey };
```

and the reducer parts:

```
const sortKey = (state = false, action) => {
  if (action.type === SORT_BY_PRICE) {
    return action.payload;
  }
  return state;
```

Comment: Where is `Input` from?

Comment: can elaborate a bit more on what you mean its not working properly?

Comment: @AndrewLi Input from ReactStrap

Comment: @promisified by not working properly I mean - I can't make him pass checked or unchecked state to redux state

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv Have you tested to see if the handler is actually called, or that state is being updated? Also, try making it a `type="checkbox"`.

Comment: @AndrewLi just noticed this bug either. Yes it helped. Second time today